# What does the `$r` do in `pd $r`?

Tags: radare2

I was just looking at the [Megabeets tutorial again](https://www.megabeets.net/a-journey-into-radare-2-part-1/), and it he has,

```
pd $r @ main
```

I don't see the the `$r` explained anywhere though. What does `$r` do in that? It's also not explained in `pd?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$r` is one of the variables available in radare2. More specifically, `$r` is a variable which holds the height of the console. This command is shown on Visual Disassembly mode (`Vp`) and usually is not executed by the user. The command is used by the mode in order to show *N* instructions from the binary where *N* is the height of the console (number of lines). This provides the user with a better, and more interactive, reverse engineering experience.

To show the full list of variables you can use the command `?$?`. Here is a truncated list:

```
[0x000008cc]> ?$?
Usage: ?v [$.]
| flag          offset of flag
| $$            here (current virtual seek)
| $$$           current non-temporary virtual seek
| $?            last comparison value
| $alias=value  alias commands (simple macros)
| $b            block size
...
| $c,$r         get width and height of terminal
...
| $l            opcode length
| $m            opcode memory reference (e.g. mov eax,[0x10] => 0x10)
| $M            map address (lowest map address)
| $MM           map size (lowest map address)
| $o            here (current disk io offset)
| $p            getpid()
| $P            pid of children (only in debug)
| $s            file size
| $S            section offset
| $SS           section size
...
| ${ev}         get value of eval config variable
| $r            get console height
| $r{reg}       get value of named register
| $k{kv}        get value of an sdb query value
| $s{flag}      get size of flag
...
```